# How to set text of another class?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, oop, ios7

What I have is menu at the top (vertical slider). On the top I have button, on clicking this button, the view will get scroll down and display the menu.

For this what I am doing is creating a view and showing it at top.

[image]

Now when I click on the button, I am planning to change the frame of top view with animation.

I am able to handle the frame and animation, however problem I am facing is setting the text to the right label and left button.

Below is the dropbox link to download the sample project. Any idea/ solution will be appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pdaelw2k8ljnaki/TwoView.zip

---

What I  tried is below code

```
CommonViewController *newClass = [[CommonViewController alloc] init];
newClass.parentObject = self;

NSLog(@"text is %@", newClass.rightSideLabel.text);

newClass.rightSideLabel.text = @"NEW VALUE HERE";
```

However still on the right side I see products only.

---

### Full Code

### CommonViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CommonViewController : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rightSideLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *leftSideButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *middleButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *topImageView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CommonViewController  *parentObject;
@end
```

### CommonViewController.m

```
#import "CommonViewController.h"

@interface CommonViewController ()

@end

@implementation CommonViewController

@synthesize topView, rightSideLabel, leftSideButton, middleButton, topImageView, parentObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -416, 320, 460)];

    topImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    topImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar_bg4.png"];

    middleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [middleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(120, topView.frame.size.height-44, 80, 44)];
    [middleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slide_arrow_open.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    leftSideButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [leftSideButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, topView.frame.size.height-44, 80, 44)];
    [leftSideButton setTitle:@"BACK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftSideButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    rightSideLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, topView.frame.size.height-40, 110, 40)];
    rightSideLabel.text = @"PRODUCTS";
    rightSideLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    rightSideLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



    [topView addSubview:topImageView];
    [topView addSubview:middleButton];
    [topView addSubview:leftSideButton];
    [topView addSubview:rightSideLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:topView];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

### bViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CommonViewController.h"

@interface bViewController : CommonViewController

@end
```

### bViewController.m

```
#import "bViewController.h"

@interface bViewController ()

@end

@implementation bViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    CommonViewController *newClass = [[CommonViewController alloc] init];
    newClass.parentObject = self;

    NSLog(@"text is %@", newClass.rightSideLabel.text);

    newClass.rightSideLabel.text = @"NEW VALUE HERE";

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

### What I want to do is keep common things in CommonViewController

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin : If you read it correctly, its not duplicate... for me its setting data and NOT passing data...

Comment: @downvoter : what is wrong in this question???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to respect MVC design Pattern approach. So instead of "newClass.rightSideLabel.text = @"NEW VALUE HERE";" You have to write :

in NewClass.h:
-@property(strong,nonatomic) stringText;

in NewClass.m:(ViewDidLoad Method)
-rightSideLabel.text=stringText;

in the current class:
-newClass.stringText= @"NEW Value HERE";

Comment: newclass is bviewcontroller in my case? I don't get you...

Comment: new class is the instance from the class(ViewController) where your Label exists

Comment: I did what you are saying... but it is not working... bcz CustomViewController didload is getting called before bViewController...

Comment: aaaaaa OK !! Use the NSNotificationCenter

Comment: in CustomViewController.m: (ViewDidAppear)
-[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(upDateLabelText:)name:@"upDateLabel" object:nil];
in CustomViewController.m:
-(void)upDateLabelText :(NSNotification*) pNotification
{
    Label.text=stringText;
}

in bViewController
After setting the stringValue
-[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"upDateLabel" object:nil];

Comment: I did... thanks for your answer... See my answer for what I did...

Answer (score 1):

Below is what I did...

In `bViewController.m`, I added below.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"New Value Here" forKey:@"notValue"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangeRightSideLabel" object:self];
```

And in `CommonViewController.m`, `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) name:@"ChangeRightSideLabel" object:nil];

- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // [notification name] should always be @"TestNotification"
    // unless you use this method for observation of other notifications
    // as well.

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"ChangeRightSideLabel"]) {
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
        trightSideLabel = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"notValue"];
        rightSideLabel.text = trightSideLabel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a string property for CommonViewController and assign the text to it.
And in CommonViewController's ViewDidLoad set that text to rightSideLabel.